# ERROR: Error fetching remote repo 'origin' when running automation test in Jenkins

Tags: git, github, jenkins, devops

I'm new to git and Jenkins.

I'm trying to run my automation project from Jenkins, when I click "Build now", I'm getting error as "*ERROR: Error fetching remote repo 'origin'*". I have tried to set git path in **Manage Jenkins>Global Tool Configuration > Path to Git executabl**e as "C:\Program Files\Git\gitrepo\bin\git.exe". But still no luck.

Below is the complete error I'm getting in console output.

```
Started by user Test User
Running as SYSTEM
    Building in workspace C:\Users\XXXXX\.jenkins\workspace\automationtestsuit
    The recommended git tool is: NONE
    using credential 5674657456745645645647jdgfhdgfhd
     - C:\Program Files\Git\gitrepo\bin\git.exe rev-parse --resolve-git-dir C:\Users\XXXXXX\.jenkins\workspace\automationtestsuit\.git # timeout=10
    Fetching changes from the remote Git repository
     - C:\Program Files\Git\gitrepo\bin\git.exe config remote.origin.url https://github.com/yyyy/zzzzzz/tree/master/autotest # timeout=10
    Fetching upstream changes from https://github.com/yyyy/zzzzzz/tree/master/autotest
     - C:\Program Files\Git\gitrepo\bin\git.exe --version # timeout=10
     - git --version # 'git version 2.24.1.windows.2'
    using GIT_ASKPASS to set credentials 
     - C:\Program Files\Git\gitrepo\bin\git.exe fetch --tags --force --progress -- https://github.com/yyyy/zzzzzz/tree/master/autotest +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/* # timeout=10
    ERROR: Error fetching remote repo 'origin'
    hudson.plugins.git.GitException: Failed to fetch from https://github.com/yyyy/zzzzzz/tree/master/autotest
        at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.fetchFrom(GitSCM.java:1003)
        at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.retrieveChanges(GitSCM.java:1244)
        at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.checkout(GitSCM.java:1308)
        at hudson.scm.SCM.checkout(SCM.java:540)
        at hudson.model.AbstractProject.checkout(AbstractProject.java:1217)
        at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.defaultCheckout(AbstractBuild.java:647)
        at jenkins.scm.SCMCheckoutStrategy.checkout(SCMCheckoutStrategy.java:85)
        at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.run(AbstractBuild.java:519)
        at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1897)
        at hudson.maven.MavenModuleSetBuild.run(MavenModuleSetBuild.java:543)
        at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:101)
        at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:442)
    Caused by: hudson.plugins.git.GitException: Command "C:\Program Files\Git\gitrepo\bin\git.exe fetch --tags --force --progress -- https://github.com/yyyy/zzzzzz/tree/master/autotest +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*" returned status code 128:
    stdout: 
    stderr: fatal: repository 'https://github.com/yyyy/zzzzzz/tree/master/autotest/' not found
        at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl.launchCommandIn(CliGitAPIImpl.java:2671)
        at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl.launchCommandWithCredentials(CliGitAPIImpl.java:2096)
        at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl.access$500(CliGitAPIImpl.java:84)
        at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl$1.execute(CliGitAPIImpl.java:618)
        at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.fetchFrom(GitSCM.java:1001)
        ... 11 more
    ERROR: Error fetching remote repo 'origin'
TestNG Reports Processing: START
Looking for TestNG results report in workspace using pattern: **/testng-results.xml
Did not find any matching files.
Finished: FAILURE*
```

Answer (score 0):

Please note the `stderr` line:

> ```
> stderr: fatal: repository
> 'https://github.com/yyyy/zzzzzz/tree/master/autotest/' not found
> ```

You have used the wrong URL for your repository!  GitHub URLs consist of the scheme, the hostname `github.com`, the user name (`yyyy` here), one slash, and the repository name (`zzzzzz`) *and then stop*.  The `/tree/master/autotest` part is definitely wrong.  I am guessing that you replaced the user and repository names, but if not, `yyyy/zzzzzz` is probably wrong as well.

Comment: Yes. After further analysis i found that we should always use repository name as https://github.com/yyyy/zzzzzz.git My case I have committed code to github from eclipse. So my pom.xml file section went inside the proj name(i.e https://github.com/yyyy/zzzzzz/tree/master/autotest/pom.xml). Hence jenkins not able to pick pom.xml from inside. We need to make sure our pom.xml and other proj files are isnide only repository(i.e https://github.com/yyyy/zzzzzz.git ).